# Converting an Object Column to Int in Python Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some csv data that looks like this:

```
    Make    Colour  Odometer (KM)   Doors   Price
0   Toyota  White   150043  4   $4,000.00
1   Honda   Red 87899   4   $5,000.00
2   Toyota  Blue    32549   3   $7,000.00
3   BMW Black   11179   5   $22,000.00
```

I want to convert the Price to an int data type so I can plot it.

I ran the following command:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)
```

But it resulted with the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$4,000.00'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `regex=True` in `str.replace`, the default is now `False`